# How can I fetch an array in a row with two colums?

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-4

I am fetching with mysqli_fetch_array 100 rows and put in in a col-md-6.

But how can I trigger a line break after 50 rows so that I have two col-md-6 for a better view?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
       <?php 
         while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
            echo '<input type="checkbox">$row['name']</input>';
         }
       ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use a counter.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
       <?php
         $i = 1; 
         while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
            echo '<input type="checkbox">', $row['name'], '</input>';
            if($i++ == 50) echo '</div>', PHP_EOL, '<div class="col-md-6">', PHP_EOL;
         }
       ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

> Note: `$row['name']` must either be interpolated within echo-quotes **or** printed out.